# how to get best time from table?

Tags: php, mysql

How to get best time from MySql table collumn which I made varchar (I can change it, just I didn't know better) which data looks like `"00:05:22.22"` (it's "hours:minutes:seconds.milliseconds").

it's like laps times in that collumn..

or I should change my DB table structure? to what? 
and how I should do it then?

i.e. 
in that collumn are records like this:

`00:00:04.99
00:00:04.57
00:00:04.55
00:00:04.58
00:00:03.36`

And I would like to get all of them ordered by shortest time. Like best lap.

Comment: What kind of time are you talking about. One that you supply, a time stamp?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question more?

Comment: What type of time do you expect from the db?

Comment: will "select* from table order by time limit 1" work? (sub in your table/column names)

edit: removed "desc"

Comment: Please provide some sample data along with the expected output.

Comment: it's a lap time and I need to get best last from all of them

Comment: What is the format of the time data? Text?

Comment: now in DB - yes.. it's varchar.. but I was searching that now it's possible to change it to I think date(6) but not working for me.. and that format is not saving milliseconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 5.6.4 or greater, you can use the TIME datatype for your column and indicate that it should accept fractional parts of a second - see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html).

Otherwise, using a VARCHAR column, you can still use the MIN/MAX functions for your data and expect to get a valid result (provided all values are correctly formatted), since alphabetically sorting the data in your use case should give the same result as numerically sorting it.

Alternatively, you can use the ORDER BY clause on that column and take just the first n results. Depends on your needs.

Comment: holly SH*T!!!
I din't thinked that in varchar field there can be used order by that kind of time structure.. :/ dum me for that I didn't tryed.. :///

Answer (score 1):

To get an ordered set from a table your query needs to specify an order -

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
ORDER BY `lap_time` ASC
```

You do not have to include `ASC` in the query as any `ORDER BY` will sort from smallest to largest unless otherwise told not to do so with `DESC`

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, your column datatype is `varchar`, you can do

`select [column_names] from [table_name] order by [column_name_containing_time] asc`

You can see an example here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7164a/3)

Comment: Oh yes, missed that. Edited the answer... :)